# Cut and Join for Hurwitz number with multiple spin

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, symmetric-functions, hurwitz-theory

Let me introduce some background of cut and join equation for spin Hurwitz number with the completed cycle as mentioned in
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.3120.pdf
We fix two partition $\mu $ and $\nu$ of a fixed integer $d$, r, s are also fixed such that
$ 2g-2+\ell(\mu)+\ell(\nu)=rs$, where $\ell()$ denote the length of the partition.

A disconnected genus $g$ double Hurwtiz number $h_{g,\mu,\nu}^r$ with completed $(r+1)$ cycle is defined as (Definition 2.5 in the paper)
$$h_{g,\mu,\nu}^r := \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{\ell(\mu)} \mu_i \prod_{i=1}^{\ell(\nu)} \nu_i}\sum_{|\lambda|=d}\chi_{\mu}^{\lambda}\Big(\frac{p_{r+1}}{(r+1)!}\Big)^s\chi_{\nu}^{\lambda} $$

We can now give the geometric meaning of Hurwitz numbers with
completed cycles it the count of the stable map with weight given by the inverse of Automorphism.
Call a stable map $f: C → \mathbb{CP}^1$
an r-covering if (i) it
has a finite number of preimages of $0$ and $\infty$ given by $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively.

and (ii) all its singular loci
have multiplicity r except possibly the preimages of $0$ and $\infty$

The generating function for this number in the paper is given by eq (31)

$$H_{r+1}(\beta, p_1\ldots, q_1\ldots) := \sum_{s,\ell(\mu), \ell(\nu)}h_{g,\mu,\nu}^{r+1}\beta^s p_{\mu}q_{\mu} $$
The above can be written in a infinite wedge space expression in the following way
$$ H_{r+1}(\beta, p_1\ldots, q_1\ldots)= \langle\exp(\sum \frac{q_m}{h m} \alpha_m)\exp(\beta \mathcal{F}_{r+1}) \exp(\sum \frac{p_m}{h m} \alpha_{-m})   \rangle$$

Now these generating functions are the solution to the cut and join the equation
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}H_{r+1}= Q_{r+1}H_{r+1}$$
where $Q_i$ as defined in theorem 5.2 these are the cut and join opertors.

My question is we allow spin say $r_1$ and $r_2$ or finitely many.We can define a similar Hurwitz number with a completed cycle. In literature, there exists a cut and join formula for these numbers?

$$ H_{r_{1}+1, r_2 +1}(\beta, p_1\ldots, q_1\ldots)= \langle\exp(\sum \frac{q_m}{h m} \alpha_m)\exp(\beta_1 \mathcal{F}_{r_1+1}+ \beta_2 \mathcal{F}_{r_2+1}) \exp(\sum \frac{p_m}{h m} \alpha_{-m})   \rangle$$